# How to cast from const void* in a constexpr expression?

Tags: c++, casting, constexpr

I'm trying to reimplement memchr as constexpr (1). I haven't expected issues as I have already successfully done the same thing with strchr which is very simmilar.

However both clang and gcc refuse to cast const void* to anything else within constexpr function, which prevents me to access the actual values.

I understand that working with void* in constexpr function is weird, as we cannot do malloc and there is no way to specify arbitrary data as literal values. I'm doing this basically as a part of an excercise to rewrite as much as I can from  as constexpr (2).

Still I'd like to know why this is not allowed and if there is any way around it.

Thank you!

(1) My implementation of memchr:

```
constexpr void const *memchr(const void *ptr, int ch, size_t count) {
    const auto block_address = static_cast<const uint8_t *>(ptr);
    const auto needle = static_cast<uint8_t>(ch);
    for (uintptr_t pos{0}; pos < count; ++pos) {
        auto byte_address = block_address + pos;
        const uint8_t value = *byte_address;
        if (needle == value) {
            return static_cast<void const *>(byte_address);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

(2) The entire project on Github: https://github.com/jlanik/constexprstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible to use `void*` in such a way in constant expressions. Casts from `void*` to other object pointer types are forbidden in constant expressions. `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden as well.

This is probably intentional to make it impossible to access the object representation at compile-time.

You cannot have a `memchr` with its usual signature at compile-time.

The best that I think you can do is write the function for pointers to `char` and its cv-qualified versions, as well as `std::byte` (either as overloads or as template), instead of `void*`.

For pointers to objects of other types it is going to be tricky in some cases and impossible in most cases to implement the exact semantics of `memchr`.

While I am not certain that it is possible, maybe, in a templated version of `memchr`, one can read the underlying bytes of the objects passed-by-pointer via a `std::bit_cast` into a struct containing a `std::byte`/`unsigned char` array of appropriate size.

Comment: If you use template typed ptrs, you still need to access individual bytes to avoid semantics change.  And that quickly becomes impossible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think only the byte-like types will work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Actually, I am wondering whether it _is_ possible to implement `memchr` as a template using `std::bit_cast` to read the underlying bytes.

Comment: seems plausible.  Bit cast each T to an array of unsigned char and search them.  The return value would be ... strange.  Might have to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I am recently experimenting with a `constexpr` `std::any` implementation and has hit the same issue. After some research<sup>1</sup>, it turns out it will be allowed in C++26 to cast a pointer-to-void to a pointer-to-object type in a constant expression, provided that the new type is similar to pointed-to object. The propsal [p2738](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2738r1.pdf) contains the following changes to the requirements of constant expressions and has been implemented in the newest version of Clang.

> An expression `E` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
> `E`, following the rules of the abstract machine[intro.execution], would
> evaluate one of the following:
> [...]
>
> - a conversion from type <del>cv void* to a pointer-to-object type</del> a prvalue `P` of type ”pointer to cv void” to a pointer-to-object type `T` unless `P` points to an object whose type is similar to `T`;

[Demo with clang(trunk) version on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbchf8zhe)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

constexpr void const *memchr(const void *ptr, int ch, std::size_t count) {
    const auto block_address = static_cast<const unsigned char *>(ptr);
    const auto needle = static_cast<unsigned char>(ch);
    for (uintptr_t pos{0}; pos < count; ++pos) {
        auto byte_address = block_address + pos;
        const unsigned char value = *byte_address;
        if (needle == value) {
            return static_cast<void const *>(byte_address);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

constexpr const unsigned char haystack[] = "ABCDEFG";
static_assert(static_cast<const unsigned char*>(memchr(haystack, 'D', 7)) - haystack == 3);
```

Of course, if your library is targeting C++14, this does not help much, but it's still a worthwhile update for the question in the title.

Note that this will not allow casting to a pointer of base class because casting a pointer-to-void directly to a base class may yield a different pointer from first casting to a pointer to a derived class then to the base class, as is shown in the following example in the proposal.

```
#include <cassert>

struct A {
    virtual void f() {};
    int a;
};
struct B {
    int b;
};
struct C: B, A {};
int main() {
    C c;
    void* v = &c;
    assert(static_cast<B*>(v) == static_cast<B*>(static_cast<C*>(v))); // Fails
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [This page](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1431) indicates it has been adopted for C++26 with strong favor and no against.